# Axios interceptors - ReferenceError: Data is not defined

Tags: javascript, axios, frontend, referenceerror

I am following Brad Traversy's course on Axios, and I just got to interceptors. I followed what he wrote but I got an error saying:

```
ReferenceError: Data is not defined
    <anonymous> http://localhost:63342/Asynchronous JS/axios-notes/main.js:87
    promise callback*r.prototype.request https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js:2
    e https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js:2
    exports https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js:2
    getTodos http://localhost:63342/Asynchronous JS/axios-notes/main.js:14
    EventListener.handleEvent* http://localhost:63342/Asynchronous JS/axios-notes/main.js:134
```

This is my interceptor code:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(
    config => {
        console.log(`${config.method.toUpperCase()} request sent to ${config.url} at ${new Data().getTime()}`);
        return config;
    },
    error => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);
```

Once I remove this piece of code and do get/post requests, everything is working again, which means there's something wrong with this piece of code.

Comment: `new Data()` ... `new Date()` perhaps? considering `.getTime()` is a method of `Date` I suspect a simple typo

Comment: Did you mean to say `new Date().getTime()` and not `new Data()`. There is a typo and hence the Reference error

Comment: Oh my god thanks why am I so dumb. dumb typo

Comment: Learn typescript.The typescript compiler helps you find missing associated dependency types.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the correct object for date is `new Date()` and not `new Data()` on this line

```
console.log(`${config.method.toUpperCase()} request sent to ${config.url} at ${new Data().getTime()}`);
```

correct it to

```
console.log(`${config.method.toUpperCase()} request sent to ${config.url} at ${new Date().getTime()}`);
```